# How to install shared library in CMAKE to custom path

Tags: cmake

I am working on a machine with no access to `/usr`, but rather a completely different path, so I cannot access `/usr/lib`, `/usr/bin` or `/usr/include`.

So I have simple directory structure under some `parent_dir`:

```
--mylib
    --file1.cpp
    --file1.h
--src
    --main.cpp
--install
```

Install dir is where I wish to keep binaries, so it should have bin, lib and include dir after installation.
Parent CMakeFiles.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(MyProject VERSION 2.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install/lib")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install/lib")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install/bin")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install/include")

add_subdirectory(mylib)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

mylib/CMakeText.txt looks like this

```
set(SOURCE_FILE     file1.cpp) 
set(SOURCE_HEADERS  file1.h)

add_library(mylib SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${SOURCE_HEADERS})

target_include_directories(mylib 
                          PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
                          PUBLIC $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INCLUDE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${SOURCE_HEADERS}")

install(TARGETS mylib EXPORT qlcsim_lib
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
```

In src/CMakeFiles.txt I have:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main mylib)
```

which works fine but is incorrect.
What it should be:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "parent_dir/install/")
find_library(MY_LIB mylib)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${MY_LIB})
```

The reason why CMakeFile.txt builds my executable properly the first time is because I am not linking to library in /install/lib (even though it's created there with no issues), but rather building the entire library into main.cpp, I think, I might be horribly wrong, this is my first cmake use.

Find library on the other hand, seems correct. However it fails to locate the library if I hint it as `find_library(my_lib HINT "parent_dir/install/lib")` and I had to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` first for `find_library` to start working. However even though a library is found, main.cpp completely fails saying: `"catastrophic error: cannot open source file "file1.h"`. Why?

I tried `include_directories(parent_dir/mylib)` (absolute path), tried `target_link_directories`. Nothing works. Headers of library mylib are installed in `install/include`, and I tried linking `main` target to there as well.

Note that mylib has about 40 .h and .cpp files and I need it as shared library by several other projects. So solution to copy paste the entire library all over again is not good.

I found out somewhere that I should be including class headers as `include <file1.h>` rather than `include "file1.h"` if library is properly installed in the system. Is that the issue? I really don't wish to dive into 80+ files fixing includes. I tried changing includes in executables which suppose to use the library (main.cpp) and issue is still there.

Comment: In CMake **installation** is performed by using [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command. Invocations of this command are "triggered" when you run `make install` from the command line. After the library is installed, the executable could find it via `find_package`. You are trying to emulate(?) installation by adjusting `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable to point into installation location. This has a little sense.

Comment: You may read CMake tutorial about what installation is: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Installing%20and%20Testing.html#install-rules. Also you may read about how to create configuration file for the installed library, this file could be used by `find_package`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html

Comment: Actually, since you build both `mylib` and `main` from the **same** CMake project, for link `main` with `mylib` you don't need to have `mylib` installed. Just pass library **target** name to `target_link_libraries` call, and CMake will care about everything else: `target_link_libraries(main mylib)`.